# API rest retornando 405 php

Tags: php, api, rest

Estou executando o seguinte código:

```
<?php

  $data_string['MerchantOrderId']                             = "2014111703";
  $data_string['Customer']['Name']                            = "Comprador Teste";
  $data_string['Payment']['Type']                             = "CreditCard";           
  $data_string['Payment']['Amount']                           = '15700';
  $data_string['Payment']['Provider']                         = "Simulado";
  $data_string['Payment']['Installments']                     = '1';
  $data_string['Payment']['CreditCard']['CardNumber']         = "1234123412341231";
  $data_string['Payment']['CreditCard']['Holder']             = "Teste Holder";
  $data_string['Payment']['CreditCard']['ExpirationDate']     = "12/2021";
  $data_string['Payment']['CreditCard']['SecurityCode']       = "123";
  $data_string['Payment']['CreditCard']['Brand']              = "Visa";

  $data_string = json_encode($data_string);

  $data = json_encode($data_string);

$ch = curl_init('https://apihomolog.braspag.com.br/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'MerchantId: 1688adsasdasdasdasdasda',
'MerchantKey: adasdasdasdsadasdaswoT')
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

A API está retornando: 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.

Como faço pra ver o response sem o erro ?

Comment: Em uma API Rest, o código de resposta geralmente indica o problema. "verb used to access this page is not allowed." Aparentemente você não pode enviar um POST para esta url.

Comment: Complementando o comentário anterior, verifique a documentação da API e veja quais os verbos que essa URL esta esperando ou aceita.
Outra coisa, acredito que você possa excluir uma das linhas: 
`$data_string = json_encode($data_string);`
 `$data = json_encode($data_string);`

Comment: Não tinha reparado, você está enviando um POST para o index. Normalmente, nem os sites "amadores" (que por natureza são mal estruturados), costumam ter alguma funcionalidade relacionada ao POST na raiz, imagina então uma API Rest.